# How to create XML in Android for several images?

Tags: java, android

How to create an xml with several images? I presume that this file should be saved in drawable folder? I mean, what should be the structure of that xml? 
To describe in more detail, for example I have a bitmap XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bitmap
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/logo_top"
android:dither="true" />
```

And it works good, untill I need to add several images, I understand that there is no way to add more bitmaps to 1 XML file, so I search the way to do so.
PS I need this technique to add images dynamically and programmatically.

Also I've tried to do that this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>    
    <bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_top"
    android:dither="true" />
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/image2"
    android:dither="true" />
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/image3"
    android:dither="true" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

But the picture didn't show up.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Describe your question in detail. Or share any screen shot so that we can understand the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Check following Tutorial to see how we can define a selector and apply on a view:

http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=56